# A function that, based on two other columns, will give us another column based on the data split

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a dataframe df that looks like this:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBLSt.png)

Later I add column "classification" where based on OBIS number and Value.

[Dataframe with classification column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cOGp.png)

The point is to create a function that will replace changing such code, where every time I increase the division into a larger number, I have to count the percentages again.
For example, here a division of 20% (5 classes):

```py
conditions = [
    (df['OBIS'] == '1.8.0') & (df['Value'] < 39469.79),
    (df['OBIS'] == '1.8.0') & (df['Value'] >= 39469.79) & (df['Value'] < 78939.58),
    (df['OBIS'] == '1.8.0') & (df['Value'] >= 78939.58) & (df['Value'] < 118409.37),
    (df['OBIS'] == '1.8.0') & (df['Value'] >= 118409.37) & (df['Value'] < 157879.16),
    (df['OBIS'] == '1.8.0') & (df['Value'] >= 157879.16),
    (df['OBIS'] == '1.9.0') & (df['Value'] < 1.41),
    (df['OBIS'] == '1.9.0') & (df['Value'] >= 1.41) & (df['Value'] < 2.82),
    (df['OBIS'] == '1.9.0') & (df['Value'] >= 2.82) & (df['Value'] < 4.22),
    (df['OBIS'] == '1.9.0') & (df['Value'] >= 4.22) & (df['Value'] < 5.63),
    (df['OBIS'] == '1.9.0') & (df['Value'] >= 5.63),
    (df['OBIS'] == '2.8.0') & (df['Value'] < 0.008),
    (df['OBIS'] == '2.8.0') & (df['Value'] >= 0.008) & (df['Value'] < 0.016),
    (df['OBIS'] == '2.8.0') & (df['Value'] >= 0.016) & (df['Value'] < 0.024),
    (df['OBIS'] == '2.8.0') & (df['Value'] >= 0.024) & (df['Value'] < 0.032),
    (df['OBIS'] == '2.8.0') & (df['Value'] >= 0.032)
    
]

values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

df["Classification"] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

I thought to make such a function based on case/switch but I think that with 12 obis numbers and location-dependent values it's not a good idea.

Mainly, I would like them to be divided into equal parts within the classification from 0 to 9, where I could choose how many classes to divide it into.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead of `np.select`:

```
df["Classification"] = [values[conditions.index(cond)] for cond in conditions if cond==True]
```